# AddOrUpdate does not modify children

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using AddOrUpdate in my seed method to keep my permissions up to date, however, in the situation where the below code is updating the existing role (rather than creating it), any new Permissions I created are not being added to the role. What am I doing wrong?

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string[]> s in new Dictionary<string, string[]>{
                {"Superuser", context.Permissions.Select<Permission, string>(p=>p.Name).ToArray()},

            })
            {
                Role r = new Role();
                r.Name = s.Key;
                r.Permissions = new List<Permission>();
                foreach (string p in s.Value)
                    r.Permissions.Add(context.Permissions.Where(per => per.Name == p).First());

                context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(i => i.Name, r);
            }

context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AddOrUpdate` only adds or updates the main entity, but not its relations.

So you have to do it in two steps:

1. Create the `Role`, and `AddOrUpdate` it. Now you can get the `RoleId` (or whatever the PK is) form your added or updated `Role`.
2. Create the `Permissions`, and set explicitly their `RoleId` (or whatever the FK is). Then `AddOrUpdate` the `Permissions`.

Comment: In this case, permissions and roles have a many-to-many relationship, so I will have to update them separately without using AddOrUpdate, but this still answers the question. Thanks!